# How to find whether user can click a given button in html using js?

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom, browser

I developed a page with only one button.

- If a valid user appears i will allow that user to click that button
  manually or user can also press enter(i will click that button using
  js in background).
- If a invalid user appears i will display a freeze layer on top of
  that button, so that user cannot click that button.

Problem is if invalid user appears and press enter. my js code will click that button.

**So, my question is straight forward is there any option in js to find whether user can click that button**

I can also make alternate flow but i need to know answer for above question.

Comment: Why don't you disable the button instead of displaying "a freeze layer on top"?

Comment: Yes, i can change my logic dude, but i need to find answer anyway. may be i can face same issue in future

Comment: Well , what do you mean by valid or invalid user? Logged in? Authenticated?
Do you want the button to be triggered automatically if the user is authenticated( you said " i will click that button using js in background" ), this is what I understand. But then, you would not need a button.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(<user_is_not_valid_(your own condition)>){
   document.getElementById("id_of_button").disabled = true;
}
```

This is for making a button unable to click. You should solve how to determine if the user is allowed to click. Put your own condition instead of *< user_is_not_valid_(your own condition) >*.

Comment: Yes i can disable the button but this is flow change not answer for above question

Answer (score 0):

The user is valid or not is based on API request fire onpage load `$.get` in success you make the `if (user.type==true){ $('#btn').addattr('onclick',funcname);}else{ ('#btn').attr('readonly',true);}`